# Make an image resize depending on content inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with two other elements, one contains the text content, another may contain a picture. The picture and text might vary in size/length. I want the parent div to grow depending on the content but only up to a certain height. If there is an image I want the image to grow or shrink to make the parent div reach the max height. If there is no image, I want the parent div to shrink to contain the text. The image will be added via JavaScript. I have illustrated what I wanted to do in the following picture.
[image: illustration]

I was expecting the following code to work but the images seem to expand to be larger than the parent div. I have tried a few other things but I cannot seem to get it to work.

[Here](https://codepen.io/Jakieboi/pen/dyWNveQ) is a codepen.

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="text-body">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div id="image">
    <img src="MayOrMayNotContainImg.com">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#parent{
  max-height:400px;
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#text-body{
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#image{
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You can set a dynamic height to the image when you are appending the same to the DOM

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? I am still a beginner in html and css

Comment: Sure, will update as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet below, if the image is there, I am assigning its height dynamically using `jQuery height` by calculating the remaining space inside the  #parent. (200 - height). So whatever the content may be, the height of the image will increase or reduce based on that.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#img-wrapper').attr('src', 'https://static.remove.bg/sample-gallery/graphics/bird-thumbnail.jpg');
  let height = $('#text-body').outerHeight();
  $('#img-wrapper').height(200 - height - 20);
})
```

```css
#parent{
  max-height:200px;
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#text-body{
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#image{
  padding:10px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div id="text-body">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  </div>
  <div id="image">
    <img id='img-wrapper' src="MayOrMayNotContainImg.com">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but I'd prefer not to have fixed values in the code. I think I can work around it with a bit of code though, thanks for the help!!